# Data Warehouse to Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi-desktop, data-warehouse, microsoft-fabric

I am using Microsoft Power BI and Microsoft Fabric to carry out an ETL project in my internship. The project involves transferring data from a SharePoint folder to a data warehouse using Data Flow Gen 2, and subsequently placing the data from this warehouse into Power BI Desktop. However, when I import the data from the warehouse into Power BI Desktop, the Power Query button (transform data) becomes disabled. I would like to know if it is possible to import data from a data warehouse and still be able to perform transformations in the Power Query of Power BI Desktop.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-live-connect-dq-datasets

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI, there are 2 connection modes: Import and DirectQuery

in Import mode, you import the data into your Power BI instance and create the required transformation if you wish.

In DirectQuery mode. you will have the metadata only, and the transformation is handled in the DWH. so you will not be able to make the transformation in the Power BI.

So, Please be sure that you are using the import mode in case of you need to make the transformation by the Power BI itself.

hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to Fabric from Power BI Desktop you can either connect to the workspace SQL endpoint, or to the semantic model.  If you connect to the semantic model, you're in "Live Connect" mode and don't import the data at all.  If you connect to the SQL endpoint you can choose Import or DirectQuery and proceed like any connection to SQL Server.